# Setting 2D Integer Array values all to 0 in C

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I am trying to set all the values in my 2D array to 0 and then print all the scores back to make sure they are correct.

```
struct Game {
    int GameScoresHome[10][10];
};

int main() {
    struct Game game;

    memset(game.GameScoresHome, 0, sizeof game.GameScoresHome);
    for (int x=0;x<100;x++) {
        int y = floor(x/10);
        printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x][y]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The current output is:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 822083893 32767 32767 32767 32767 32767 32767 1651067951 1634028652 1345283180 1702057263 1701080931 2054842477 1866870631 1885417061 1647262318 1146113364 896624241 1280918623 1919052108 1819042146 1818850626 1634956149 1852133983 1264923239 792545364 1666723698 1836345960 1163089152 1949263220 1919250021 1868774725 1213481296 796026224 1785230711 1650803759 792546380 1213481296 1868781615 1752003690 6780258 1497628720 778396783 1920232291 792545364 1666723698 1836345960 1735746149 796026224 1785230711 1650803759 0 0 3 0 7 0 -2147482624 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 233472 1869045599 48 1868783455 5312 1633967967 3480 1818320735 304 1919115103 0 1852796269 0 115 0 72 0 1227 0 0
```

The first 11 zeros are as they should be then it all goes wrong. What's going on?

Comment: Use `printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x%10][y]);`

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing memory outside the array.

Your `x` variable iterates from 0 to 99.

```
for (int x=0;x<100;x++)
```

But your array has only 10 rows.

```
int GameScoresHome[10][10];
```

One fix would be to use simple nested loops.

```
for (int x=0;x<10;x++) {
   for (int y=0;y<10;y++) {
      printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x][y]);
   }
}
```

Nested loops would also make it easy to include a newline after each row.

```
for (int x=0;x<10;x++) {
   for (int y=0;y<10;y++) {
      printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x][y]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
for (int x=0;x<100;x++) {
        int y = floor(x/10);
        printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x][y]);
    }
```

the `x` value is going out of bound. Maybe you want to take a `%10` value of `x` and change the index locations, like

```
  printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[y][x%10]);
```

or, use a nested loop to maintain two indexes separately.

Answer (score 0):

Write the loop simpler

```
for ( int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x / 10][x % 10]);
}
```

or

```
for ( int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x / 10][x % 10]);
    if ( x % 10 == 9 ) printf( "\n" );
}
```

As for your loop then x is being changed from 0 up to 100 and as result using x as the first index in the statement

```
printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x][y]);
                                ^^^
```

is invalid. And y is calculated incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
struct Game game = {.GameScoresHome = {0}};
for (int x=0;x<10;x++) {
   for (int y=0;y<10;y++) {
      printf("%d ",game.GameScoresHome[x][y]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```